# forward- and backward adjusting stockprices

Tags: corporate-actions

Do you guys know if a paper has been published that discusses forward- and backward adjusted stockprices, and the look ahead bias coming from backward adjusted data?

Comment: There is no look ahead bias when you backward adjust price data in a market standardized fashion, hence no paper needed to do just that.

Comment: That's what many people claim though. Do you know about a general paper discussing backward and forward adjustments for corporate actions.

Comment: @Paznaz Who claims this? Show us an example. Adjusting a stock price for corporate actions is a requirement, not some fuzzy approach to valuation. There is no "bias" when subtracting dividends that have already been paid, or multiplying the shares outstanding by a split that has already occurred.

Comment: I have no published paper on this, but when you are backtesting using backward adjusted data, you are using information that is not available in the market at the time of the backtest, hence you have look ahead bias. Forward adjusting (undoing the corporate action effect) is generally seen as the better approach.

Comment: Forward-adjusting is preferable because it prevents negative prices, not because of some fear of look-ahead bias.

Comment: Does anyone know or have a published (or not) paper on the above topic of forward or backward adjustment?

Comment: @Paznaz If you have a question about anything relating to this site, leave a comment like everyone else. **Do not email my personal account about issues related to Stack Exchange.**

Comment: Maybe you should try do describe an example in full detail. In doing so, edit your own question instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Ernest Chan talks about how backward adjusted prices induce a look-ahead bias in the comments of one of his blog posts, [Beware of Low Frequency Data](http://epchan.blogspot.com/2015/04/beware-of-low-frequency-data.html). Scroll down in the comments to when he's responding to Samuel. Essentially when using backward adjusted prices, you must look at the entire dataset and *backward* adjust everything so that the latest adjusted price will match the latest true price but any price in the adjusted series before a corporate action will deviate from the unadjusted price. With a forward adjusted price series, the unadjusted and adjusted prices will match at the beginning but then after any corporate action, the adjusted and unadjusted will deviate so the latest prices will be different but there's no look-ahead bias. I'm not sure of any paper discussing this but what I've said is basically all there is to it.